# Create an msi from WindowsForms project c#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer

I am trying to create an installer for a project, But I don't know much how to do it? I've read some articles [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/creating-an-msi-package-for-C-Sharp-windows-application-using-a-v/) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx)

In those steps which describe the procedure of setup installer after adding a new project we should select   **s Setup and Deployment Projects** in the dialog box so my issue was that !! , in My dialog box I don't have **setup and Deployment Projects**.

I'am using visual studio Community.

Can anyone help me.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `Other Project Types` you should see `Setup and Deployment`.

I believe in VS 2013 only the `InstallShield Limited Edition` is included so you can get the Installer Projects extension [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Comment: Thanks @Barry O'Kane

Comment: No problem at all.